How to Transfer Period of time to datebase row in Oracle table
I have a table in oracle database like



Effective From Date
Effective To Date
Item




20240531
20241025
0001


20240602
20241020
0002



Is there any function that helps me to transfer to database like



Date
Item




20240531
0001


20240601
0001


20240602
0001


20240603
0001


...
...


20241025
0001


20240602
0002


...
...


20241020
0002



Thank you
I do not have any idea how to do this in SQL.

This can be achieved by join to calendar table

If this is a one time only issue and you will never need it again, you can use CONNECT BY as explained here. Otherwise create a calendar table.

Use a LATERAL join to a row generator:
SELECT dt,
       item
FROM   table_name
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT Effective_From_Date + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY Effective_From_Date + LEVEL - 1 <= Effective_To_Date
       );

Note: If your date values are stores as numbers or strings (don't) then use TO_DATE to convert them to dates and then use the same technique.
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Effective_From_Date, Effective_To_Date, Item) AS
SELECT DATE '2024-05-31', DATE '2024-10-25', '0001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-06-02', DATE '2024-10-20', '0002' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DT
ITEM




2024-05-31 00:00:00
0001


2024-06-01 00:00:00
0001


2024-06-02 00:00:00
0001


...
...


2024-10-23 00:00:00
0001


2024-10-24 00:00:00
0001


2024-10-25 00:00:00
0001


2024-06-02 00:00:00
0002


2024-06-03 00:00:00
0002


2024-06-04 00:00:00
0002


...
...


2024-10-18 00:00:00
0002


2024-10-19 00:00:00
0002


2024-10-20 00:00:00
0002



fiddle

Alternatively, for sample data as
SQL> WITH
  2     temp (from_date, TO_DATE, item)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT DATE '2024-05-31', DATE '2024-10-25', '0001' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT DATE '2024-06-02', DATE '2024-10-20', '0002' FROM DUAL)

query begins here:
  7    SELECT from_date + COLUMN_VALUE - 1 AS dt, item
  8      FROM temp
  9           CROSS JOIN
 10           TABLE (
 11              CAST (
 12                 MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL
 13                                 FROM DUAL
 14                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TO_DATE - from_date + 1) AS SYS.odcinumberlist))
 15  ORDER BY item, dt;

DT               ITEM
---------------- ----
31.05.2024 00:00 0001
01.06.2024 00:00 0001
02.06.2024 00:00 0001
03.06.2024 00:00 0001
<snip>
22.10.2024 00:00 0001
23.10.2024 00:00 0001
24.10.2024 00:00 0001
25.10.2024 00:00 0001
02.06.2024 00:00 0002
03.06.2024 00:00 0002
04.06.2024 00:00 0002
05.06.2024 00:00 0002
<snip> 
18.10.2024 00:00 0002
19.10.2024 00:00 0002
20.10.2024 00:00 0002

289 rows selected.

SQL>

